# Maximum value of an expression

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I am reading about the fixed-point iteration method and in the process I stumbled upon a claim that given

$\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n > 0$

and

$x = \sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i e_i$

for an arbitrary finite n
$
\max_{x\neq0}\frac{\lambda_1\xi^2_1+\lambda_2\xi^2_2+\cdots+\lambda_n \xi^2_n}{\xi^2_1+\xi^2_2+\cdots+\xi^2_n} = \lambda_1.
$

How can I prove it?
I proved this for n = 2 using partial derivatives but I am not sure I can do this for larger values of n since derivatives look more [scary](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdc%20%28a_1%20*%20b_1%5E2%20%2B%20a_2%20*%20c%5E2%20%2B%20a_3%20*%20d_3%5E2%29%20%2F%20%28b%5E2%20%2B%20c%5E2%20%2B%20d%5E2%29).

Comment: In the numerator by replacing all $\lambda$'s by $\lambda_1$ we get that the maximum is less than or equal to $\lambda_1$. By taking $x=e_1$ we can see that it is attained.

Comment: In the set where max is taking, where is $x$?

Comment: X is defined above as a linear combination of eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

Leandro answered my question: all I need to do is just to replace all $\lambda$ with $\lambda_1$ to get an upper bound.